# Why does .htaccess only receive index.php as input

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I have added a .htaccess file to my root folder, and i wanted everything written after the / to be sent to the index.php file as get data.

My root path looks like this http://www.site.com/folder/ and my .htaccess is located in the folder directory together with index.php

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?args=$1
```

Now, what ever i write behind folder/ in my url, args is "index.php". So when i visit www.site.com/folder/lots/of/bogey the args variable is "index.php"

My goal is obviously to have the args variable be "lots/of/bogey". Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because after executing the RewriteRule and getting `index.php?args=...` the `RewriteRule` gets called again. Now `index.php` is your filename, so it get's passed as args. After this mod_rewrite aborts due to recursion. To fix this, add a `RewriteCond` which enures the file isn't `index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a RewriteCond. The following will work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?args=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The L makes it stop matching rewrite rules, and QSA is for appending to query string in a rewrite rule. Refer to [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule)

Comment: No, this will not work. Even though it is the [L]ast RewriteRule in this pass, mod_rewrite will call itself again with the new, rewritten filname - which will be index.php!

Comment: @nikic. What do you mean it will not work.. I actually tested this and it worked.

Comment: @nikic. Also software like Drupal also does the same.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have at least to exclude index.php from the redirect:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^index\.php$
RewriteRule .* index.php?args=$0 [QSA,B]
```

Comment: It would be better for my image tags if i could exclude any input containing ".". Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: @Code Substitute the rewritecond I gave for `RewriteCond $0 !\.`. Since "index.php" has a dot, this catches the case of index.php too

Comment: RewriteCond $0 !\. is what i did, and it worked wonders. Thanks